# Displaying 2 times table using two for loops

Tags: c#

I'm still new to programming so please be gentle. I was trying to display the two times table first using one for statement and then using two for statements. I was wondering why my embedded for loop doesn't work. I get an unreachable error message and I don't know what to do in order to fix it. I have tried declaring "j" outside the for statement but with no effect.

/*

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 2; j <= 20; j+=2)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("1 x {0} = {1}",i, j);
                break; 
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine(); 
        */



/*  
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("2 x {0} = {1}", i, i * 2);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
 */
```

Comment: why do you need Console.ReadLine? You need one for loop and just perform/print the multiplication

Comment: I believe it is to pause the console so that he/she can see the result otherwise the console would quickly disappear

Answer (score 2):

The break in your second loop makes you exit as soon as it enters the second loop (I believe that's why you get an "unreachable code" error). Try removing the break statement as below :

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
   for (int j = 2; ;)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{j} x {i} = {i * j}");
        break;
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: When I do that I get this: 
1 x 1 = 2
1 x 1 = 4
1 x 1 = 6
1 x 1 = 8
1 x 1 = 10
1 x 1 = 12
1 x 1 = 14
1 x 1 = 16
1 x 1 = 18
1 x 1 = 20

Comment: I updated my answer. I guess I don't really understand why you want to use two for loop when you can only use one ?

Comment: I was just wondering why it was working the way I intended it to. Now i have my answer. Thank you.